# How to find the corresponding original values from a wired glm diagnose plot?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, residuals

I analyzed my count data with Poisson GLM, before I fit a model, I check my original response data, there were no obvious outliers.

[image]

However, there were some quite weird values in the diagnose model plots.

Are there some methods I can go back to check my original dataset, or some other ways can make my GLM model better fitted?

How can I identify where the wired values from?

[image: Residuals vs fitted]

Comment: Identify the value which is being predicted as -15 and see what the predictor variables are and then in conjunction with your knowledge of the underlying science work out why that is happening.

Comment: @mdewey, I know that for outliers detecting, there is a function, we can directly find which raw data caused the outliers. But I don't know if there also is a function to use for diagnosing plots. Otherwise, yes, I should do it by manually. Thank you.